# Как открыть и запустить файл в запароленном zip архиве?

Tags: c#

Тоесть нужно запустить файл из запароленного зип архива, без разархивации.

Comment: Может быть и вовсе без пароля?

Comment: я имел виду зная пароль, ну или без разархивации не получится?

Comment: Разархивировать в память хотя бы придется. Даже если и не на диск.

Comment: окей, понял....

Comment: смотрите [сюда](https://blog.aspose.com/2020/04/23/unzip-files-in-password-protected-zip-archives-in-csharp-asp.net/#Unzip-password-protected-ZIP-files-in-C#)